# Is it possible to install the core apps on unity-next?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-touch

I have installed Unity-Next on Ubuntu 13.04. Now I want to try my apps and the core-apps on unity-next instead of a real device.

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed be able to install them from the [Core Apps PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/+archive/daily), in the same way you can install them either on a device or on a desktop running the current Unity version.

You can install them in one go with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-calculator-app ubuntu-calendar-app ubuntu-clock-app ubuntu-docviewer-app ubuntu-emailclient-app ubuntu-facebook-app ubuntu-filemanager-app ubuntu-rssreader-app ubuntu-terminal-app ubuntu-weather-app ubuntu-youtube-app
```

Comment: This works but the Apps are not installed **in** Unity-Next. Is this possible too? But thanks for the answer! Now I can test all the Apps :)

Comment: Ah, in that case, I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Could you please define what you exactly mean by "installed in Unity Next"? You mean the apps are not showing up in the Dash?

Comment: I thought that you can use Unity-Next as something like the Android Emulator, so that you can install your apps in the emulator and they show up in the home screen. Is this possible?

Comment: I think there might be some confusion here. Unity Next is no more that the Ubuntu UI shell, which is a replacement written in QML of the original Unity shell based on Nux. There is neither an emulator nor a simulator for Ubuntu, nor it is functionality that would ever be added to the shell.